# How to run a .ipa file on an iOS Simulator on Mac?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a .ipa file. I want to run the iOS App on the iOS Simulator on my mac. Would appreciate if anyone could please let me know how can I run .ipa file on iOS Simuilator? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[The iOS Simulator is not an emulator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113055/37797), so ARM-compiled IPAs for iOS devices won’t run on Intel Macs.

If you have an M1 ARM Mac, you can run iOS apps officially on macOS. You might be able to copy the .app bundle inside the IPA (it’s just a zip) to the simulator’s Applications folder, but I don’t have an M1 Mac to try.